# SAS cap 1st and 99th percentiles of dataset with hundreds of variables

Tags: sas, dataset, percentile

I have a SAS dataset with 700 columns (variables). For all 700 of them, I want to cap all values below the 1st percentile to the 1st percentile and all values above the 99th percentile to the 99th percentile. I want to do this iteratively for all 700 variables without having to specify their names explicitly.

How can I do this?

Comment: How would you do it for one variable?

Comment: @Joe, maybe something like this (https://gist.github.com/statgeek/31316a678433a1db8136)? Although it certainly isn't convenient.

Comment: Ugh, definitely not that way! So slow, so many passes through the data set.

Comment: Thanks @Joe lol, not really designed for 100's of variables for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps slightly easier than the hash table - and somewhat faster, I believe - is using the *horizontal* output of `proc means`, and then using an array.

```
proc means data=sashelp.prdsale;
var _numeric_;
output out=quantiles p1= p99= /autoname;
run;

proc sql;
  select name 
    into :numlist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='SASHELP' and memname='PRDSALE' and type='num';
quit;


data prdsale_capped;
  set sashelp.prdsale;
  if _n_ eq 1 then set quantiles;
  array vars &numlist.;
  array p1 actual_p1--month_p1;
  array p99 actual_p99--month_p99;
  
  do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
    vars[_i] = max(min(vars[_i],p99[_i]),p1[_i]);
  end;
run;
```

Basically it's just setting up three arrays - vars, p1, p99 - and then you have all 3 values *for every numeric variable* on the PDV and can just compare during a single array traversal.

For a production process I'd probably not use the `--` but instead make 3 lists from `proc sql` and make 100% sure they're in the same order by using an `order by`.

Comment: Great method. I really like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `proc means` and a hash table lookup. Let's create some test data with 100 variables pulled from a normal distribution. For testing, we'll change all the variables in the first and second rows to really big and really small numbers.

Our approach: create a lookup table where we can find the variable's name, pull its percentiles, and compare its value against those percentiles.

```
data have;
    array var[100];

    do i = 1 to 100;
        do j = 1 to dim(var);
            var[j] = rand('normal');

            /* Test values */
            if(i = 1) then var[j] = 99999;
            if(i = 2) then var[j] = -99999;
        end;

        output;
    end;

    drop i j;
run;
```

Data:

```
var1              var2            var3         ...
99999             99999           99999        ...
-99999            -99999         -99999        ...
-0.149875111      0.4455504523   -0.783127138  ...
-0.731432437      -0.572508065   -1.044928486  ...
0.0108184539      1.0605591996   1.9132874927  ...
...             ...             ...            ...
```

Let's get all the percentiles with `proc means`. You might be tempted to use `output out=`, but it does not create the data in a vertical lookup table that's easy for us to use in this manner; however, the `stackODSOutput` option on `proc means` does. [More info on this from Rick Wicklin](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/10/23/percentiles-in-a-tabular-format.html).

We'll use `ods select none` so we don't render a large table but still produce the dataset that drives the table.

```
/* Get a dataset of all 1st and 99th percentiles for each variable */
ods select none;

proc means data=have stackODSOutput p1 p99;
    var var1-var100;

    ods output summary = percentiles;
run;

ods select all;
```

Note that all the percentiles will be the same in this case. This is expected. We set all the variables in the first and second rows to the same big and small numbers for easy testing.

Data:

```
Variable    P1       P99   ...
var1        -50001   50001 ...
var2        -50001   50001 ...
var3        -50001   50001 ...
var4        -50001   50001 ...
...         ...      ...   ...
```

Now we'll use our lookup approach. We know our variable names and we can store them in an array. We can loop through that array, look up the variable in the hash table by name with `vname()`, and get its percentile.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array var[*] var1-var100;

    /* Load a table of these values into memory and search for each percentile.
       Think of this like a simple lookup table that floats out in memory.
    */
    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        length variable $32.;

        dcl hash pctiles(dataset: 'percentiles');
            pctiles.defineKey('variable');
            pctiles.defineData('p1', 'p99');
        pctiles.defineDone();

        call missing(p1, p99);
    end;

    /* Get the 1st and 99th percentile of each variable. 
       If the variable's name matches the variable name
       in the hash table, check the variable's value 
       against the lookup percentile. 
       Cap it if it's above or below the percentile.
    */
    do i = 1 to dim(var);
        if(pctiles.Find(key:vname(var[i]) ) = 0) then do;

            if(var[i] < p1) then var[i] = p1;
                else if(var[i] > p99) then var[i] = p99;

        end;
    end;

    drop i variable p1 p99;
run;
```

Output:

```
var1              var2            var3          ...
50000.532908      50000.721522    99999         ...
-50000.61447      -50000.92196   -50001.19549   ...
-0.149875111      0.4455504523   -0.783127138   ...
-0.731432437      -0.572508065   -1.044928486   ...
0.0108184539      1.0605591996   1.9132874927   ...
...             ...             ...             ...
```

If your variables do not follow an easy sequential name, you can use the `--` shortcut. For example, `varA varB varC varD` can be selected by `varA--varD`.

Comment: In your case I think `array var[*] _numeric_;` probably will work (it won't for my example, unfortunately, but it would for this).